# Why is RewriteRule bad flag delimiters?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is causing this? I reviewed other examples in the project but this one eludes me.

When I remove the second rule everything works fine. Why is that? What is incorrect about the second rule?

```
RewriteRule ^.*startAd$ /post-ad-step-1.php
RewriteRule ^.*startAd/(.*) $ /post-ad-step-2.php?adType=$1
```

**Solution** remove the white space before the $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space before `$` to make it

```
RewriteRule ^.*startAd/(.*)$ /post-ad-step-2.php?adType=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: just saw that myself! :) Thanks!